# Is it possible to sort objects by multiple properties using usort in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, object, usort

I have an object that is somewhat like this:

```
<?php
class Change {
        private $prop1, $prop2, $prop3;

        public function __construct($prop1, $prop2, $prop3) {
                $this->$prop1=$prop1;
                $this->$prop2=$prop2;
                $this->$prop3=$prop3;
        }

        public function getProp1() {
                return $this->prop1;
        }

        public function getProp2() {
                return $this->prop2;
        }

        public function getProp3() {
                return $this->prop3;
        }
}
?>
```

I've removed some of the details, but that is generally what the objects are. Right now, I want to sort objects with `prop1` not equal to `NULL` at the top then sort by specific values for `prop2`. `Prop2` can be equal to "High", "Medium", "Low", "Critical", or any other value the user enters. I want to sort them in this order: Critical, High, Medium, Low, everything else. Finally, I want to sort on `prop3` alphabetically.

Is this possible in to do with usort? Is there an easier way?

Sort Order:

- `Prop1` - Not `NULL`
- `Prop2` - "Critical", "High", "Medium", "Low", *
- `Prop3` - Alphabetical

Answer (score 1):

```
function sort($a,$b){
    $criteria = array('Critical'=>4,'High'=>3,'Medium'=>2,'Low'=>1);
    if($a.Prop1 != NULL && $b.Prop1 == NULL) return -1;
    if($criteria[$a.Prop2] != $criteria[$b.Prop2]) {
        if($criteria[$a.Prop2] < $criteria[$b.Prop2]){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return strcmp($a.Prop3,$b.Prop3);
}
```

Sorry, I don't test it, but it must work in this way